# Mikrotik PPTP и IPv6 как связать

Tags: mikrotik, ipv6, pptp

В первом случае есть выделенный адрес от провайдера, настроить ipv6  получилось просто с 6to4 Tunnel.

Local address : 195.18.17.86

Remote address : 193.0.203.203

И надпись running всё хорошо.

Второй случай это PPTP связь. Там есть выделенный ip. PPTP настроил, работает. Но при включении туннеля 6to4 - он не работает (не включается автоматом). И любые танцы с настройками, дополнительными роутерами ничего не дают.

Как правильно соединить связь между интерфейсами 6to4 Tunnel и PPTP Client ? В каком порядке ? Кто должен быть первым ? Или параллельно  в одном роутере ? И как всё это сделать с помощью Firewall NAT Mangle ?

Пингую с рабочей сети на вторую, получаю почему-то зацикливание.

```
$ traceroute 2a03:e2c0:bcc:5555::1
traceroute to 2a03:e2c0:bcc:5555::1 (2a03:e2c0:bcc:5555::1), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  2a03:e2c0:bde:5555:: (2a03:e2c0:bde:5555::)  0.406 ms  0.375 ms  0.350 ms
 2  2a03:e2c0:bde::1 (2a03:e2c0:bde::1)  30.270 ms  31.536 ms  31.194 ms
 3  2a04:5200::1 (2a04:5200::1)  32.936 ms  32.912 ms  32.879 ms
 4  2a03:e2c0:bde::1 (2a03:e2c0:bde::1)  32.832 ms  32.414 ms  31.312 ms
 5  2a04:5200::1 (2a04:5200::1)  32.928 ms  32.738 ms  32.882 ms
 6  * * *
```